# objective c - change fieldtext string to * like a password

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, textfield, spritebuilder

I'm working with cocos2D & Spritebuilder while I'm trying to figure out how to make a password CCTextField but I would like some help to change the string into * for every symbol,letter or number you fill in the CCTextField.

Currently I have the following:

AccountVariables.h

```
#ifndef ProjectName_AccountVariables_h
#define ProjectName_AccountVariables_h

BOOL passwordCheck;

NSString *password;

#endif
```

Details.h

```
{
CCLabelTTF *showWarning;

CCTextField *passwordField;
}
```

Details.m

```
-(void)didLoadFromCCB
{
passwordField.string = password;
showWarning.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
}


-(void)passwordField:(CCTextField*)passwordF
{
password = passwordF.string;
[self checkAll];
}


-(void)checkAll;
{
if (password.length == 0)
    {
        showWarning.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Please fill it in"];
        passwordCheck = false;
    }
    else if (password.length < 6)
    {
        showWarning.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"it is too short!"];
        passwordCheck = false;
    }
    else if (password.length > 16)
    {
        showWarning.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"it is too long!"];
        passwordCheck = false;
    }
    else
    {
        passwordCheck = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `CCTextFiedld` hold a reference to the UITextfield object. The property is called:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) UITextField *textField
```

Get the instance of the UITextField object and set `secureTextEntry` property to `YES`.